# Android Broadcast receiver - how to get package name

Tags: android, android-broadcast

How to get the package name of music player when the broadcast receiver calls the application. i used set of playsate and metachanged broadcast reciver to get the rid of music player. i need to get the package name of music player which i currently playing. I am not sure this would be possible. if anyone having idea, please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the currently active package name and activity name using the following code,

```
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
                    + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Package ::"
                    + componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

or

```
if(isMusicActive().equalsto(true))
{
public static String PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
// get package name of player.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what should am consists of. it should get values from context. can you please explan more about (am) please